# Short circuit of solenoid's windings

Tags: short-circuit, inductance, solenoid

I wanted to short a solenoid, so   I just touched the wire of two adjacent loops at a point somewhere in between of solenoid, but now I wanted to know  what changes occur in its inductance and resistance?  .   How to draw it's equivalent circuit (i.e shorted L-R circuit) ? so that I can use it for other electrical purposes.

Comment: Drwa two coupled inductors, connected, (like an auto-transformer) and short the terminals on the shorted one. The effect on the overall inductance will depend on the coupling coefficient (which should be high, ie fairly close to 1)

Comment: from what I understand, you meant you just have one coil, and you shorted one of the loops. Basically, your current will skip one loop, so you will lose one loop of inductance (you will have two series inductors connected via your short to one another, and series inductance is just the sum of inductances). So if you have 100 loops. now you'll have 99 loops, that's it

Comment: Thanks, both answers are almost similar, so basically if I use this shorted  solenoid and consider  it as equivalent to  original  solenoid (without shorting) with just a loop less and it works similar to original solenoid?

Comment: @user215805 no you can't assume that at all unless you are applying DC. Even with an applied DC voltage the inductance may be a fraction of what it was previously. You need to come clean with how you are using the solenoid and how it's constructed.

Comment: @Ilya That's not it. A shorted turn on a solenoid will reduce the indcutance. The more tightly it's coupled into the inductor, the lower the inductance will be. For an ideally coupled shorted turn, the inductance of the whole solenoid will drop to zero. Needless to say, you can't get an ideally coupled turn on a solenoid, but you can on a toroid. So the drop in inductance will be somewhere between insignificant, and significant, depending on the coupling. The coupling is function of where the turn is on the solenoid, and how much air there is in the magnetic circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnetic core is left out of the drawing to keep it less dense.

The next schematic is as exact as possible when the capacitances and core losses are negleted. A and B are the original coil ends.

[image]

The mid section is the shorted part and the red wire is the shortcut. It's practically impossible to predict which are the mutual inductances M1, M2, M3 and which are the inductances and resistances of the sections. Even having perfect drawing and exact material facts doesn't make it easy. Good measuring equipment (much more than a multimeter) can help to find the values. But it's complex, too.

Inductances and mutual inductances depend heavily also on the magnetic circuit.

Know that the circuit can be considered as shorted transformer which can be quite tight one if there's a closed magnetic circuit.

Comment: So what about if as in above  comments it is suggested to just reduce one loop and calculate the inductance, isn't that a good method?

Comment: @user215805 Behaviour with AC or otherwise fast changing voltages very likely changes radically if you have even a single shorted turn. For pure constant DC the method is OK

Comment: Also, the current induced in that one shorted turn may burn it up if left on long.